# Performing additional computation in a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I have written a method that calculates the total depth of the nodes in a binary search tree using recursion. Is there a way to compute the average depth of the BST in the same method?

Here is the actual method

```
public int getTotalDepth(Node<T> rootNode, int depth)
    {
        if(rootNode==null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return depth + getTotalDepth(rootNode.left, depth+1) + getTotalDepth(rootNode.right, depth+1);
    }
```

Comment: You definition of *total* depth is the sum of depths of *all* nodes, not just leaf nodes? Hmmm..... Anyway, normal formula for average is `average = total / count`, so if you have another recursive method for calculating "count" of *all* nodes, you have what you need. Unless you absolutely need a single recursive method calculating both at the same time, but why not keep them separate?

Comment: @Andreas I am required to achieve this with just a single method.

Comment: Then you need an object with two fields, so a single return value (the object) can carry two values.